# C++ using DEV-C++ compiler and I wrote a program to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit but I keep getting error in equation

Tags: c++

I have written this program to learn programming, and I keep getting errors with the equation part and when it compiles it does not provide the correct answer but gives me the same answer I have input. I would like some help to show what I have done wrong please. Here is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    double ftemp, ctemp;

    cout << "Input the Fahrenheit temp and press ENTER: ";
    cin >> ftemp;

    ctemp = (ftemp - 32) / 1.8);

    cout << "Celec temp is: " << ctemp << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `I keep getting errors with the equation part and when it compiles it does not provide the correct answer` - at the moment it doesn't compile because you have too make `)` - you need to ask a better question - tell us exactly what is wrong (like what is the answer it does get).

Comment: ... and please don't say your test input is -40 :P

Comment: That's F->C by the way, not C->F as your title states.

Answer (score 0):

That code won't even compile since:

```
ctemp = (ftemp - 32) / 1.8);
```

has too many closing parentheses.

Fix that and it will work fine:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    double ftemp, ctemp;
    cout << "Input the Fahrenheit temp and press ENTER: ";
    cin >> ftemp;

    ctemp = (ftemp - 32) / 1.8;
    cout << "Celsius temp is: " << ctemp << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

as in:

```
Input the Fahrenheit temp and press ENTER: 98
Celsius temp is: 36.6667
```

---

If you *do* get it to compile and you get the same value you input, then you're either entering `-40` (which is the same in Celsius *and* Fahrenheit) or you're printing out `ftemp` rather than `ctemp`.

Comment: Now its working!!! Thank you guys so much for the help and for fixing how I wrote my question. Sorry for not asking it the right way, and I had it compile and got the right answer.